# Issue with libfmt and locale: Alignment is not correct

Tags: c++, fmt

I try to format some floating point numbers using the appropriate number separator character. In the following example, the last output line is not formatted correctly (It is shifted by one to the left).

Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/format.h>

int main()
{
    double value1{5.50};
    double value2{10.50};

    std::cout << fmt::format("{:6.2f} €", value1) << std::endl; // OK
    std::cout << fmt::format("{:6.2f} €", value2) << std::endl; // OK

    std::locale myLocale("de_DE.UTF-8");
    std::cout << fmt::format(myLocale, "{:6.2Lf} €", value1) << std::endl; // OK
    std::cout << fmt::format(myLocale, "{:6.2Lf} €  <- !!!", value2) << std::endl; // !!!
}
```

Output:

> ```
>   5.50 €
>  10.50 €
>   5,50 €
> 10,50 €  <- !!!
> ```

Why is that? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: And what version of `{fmt}` are you using?

Comment: (fwiw, It looks ok on Fedora 37 with g++ 12.2.1 and the trunk version of `{fmt}`)

Comment: Good questions (sorry)! I tried with GCC 12.2.1 and clang++ 15.0.7 on Arch Linux. fmt is 9.1.0.

Comment: (And on Fedora 37 with g++ 12.2.1 and fmt 9.1.0, I have the same issue.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this:

- I built `{fmt}` 9.1.0 and linked with your program. I was able to reproduce the same issue you have.
- I built `{fmt}` trunk (currently `050293646fc0337cfdb5084bf16f3d6efc84e9d8`) and linked with your program. The issue did not appear.

Conclusion: I suspect that 9.1.0 has a bug that does not appear in later versions. I suggest rebuilding `{fmt}` based on the commit I used or later.

Comment: You're right. I can confirm that fmt trunk works as expected. Thanks!